# Examples of monoids/semigroups in programming

Tags: language-agnostic, math, computer-science, monoids, abstract-algebra

It is well-known that monoids are stunningly ubiquitous in programing. They are so ubiquitous and so useful that I, as a 'hobby project', am working on a system that is completely based on their properties (distributed data aggregation). To make the system useful I need useful monoids :)

I already know of these:

- Numeric or matrix sum
- Numeric or matrix product
- Minimum or maximum under a total order with a top or bottom element (more generally, join or meet in a bounded lattice, or even more generally, product or coproduct in a category)
- Set union
- Map union where conflicting values are joined using a monoid
- Intersection of subsets of a finite set (or just set intersection if we speak about semigroups)
- Intersection of maps with a bounded key domain (same here)
- Merge of sorted sequences, perhaps with joining key-equal values in a different monoid/semigroup
- Bounded merge of sorted lists (same as above, but we take the top N of the result)
- Cartesian product of two monoids or semigroups
- List concatenation
- Endomorphism composition.

Now, let us define a quasi-property of an operation as a property that holds up to an equivalence relation. For example, list concatenation is quasi-commutative if we consider lists of equal length or with identical contents up to permutation to be equivalent.

Here are some quasi-monoids and quasi-commutative monoids and semigroups:

- Any (a+b = a or b, if we consider all elements of the carrier set to be equivalent)
- Any satisfying predicate (a+b = the one of a and b that is non-null and satisfies some predicate P, if none does then null; if we consider all elements satisfying P equivalent)
- Bounded mixture of random samples (xs+ys = a random sample of size N from the concatenation of xs and ys; if we consider any two samples with the same distribution as the whole dataset to be equivalent)
- Bounded mixture of weighted random samples
- Let's call it "topological merge": given two acyclic and non-contradicting dependency graphs, a graph that contains all the dependencies specified in both. For example, list "concatenation" that may produce any permutation in which elements of each list follow in order (say, 123+456=142356).

Which others do exist?

Comment: I rolled back the changes to tags, because IMO the question is not at all about functional programming.

Comment: Offtopic: How to fold a monoid using parallel computations?

Comment: @Andrey If the monoid is commutative, you may just add up the values in arbitrary order, on arbitrary threads/processors/machines, until only one value remains (or you can make it remain 1 value per machine and somehow add them up only during read access, etc.). I'm going to use only commutative monoids. If the monoid is non-commutative, then you add up the values using a balanced tree built on the values list: levels are traversed sequentially, but the nodes at each level may be reduced in parallel. See also the works of Guy Blelloch on vector parallelism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quotient monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_monoid#Homomorphisms_and_congruences) is another way to form monoids (quasimonoids?): given monoid M and an equivalence relation ~ compatible with multiplication, it gives another monoid. For example:

- **finite multisets with union**: if A* is a free monoid (lists with concatenation), ~ is "is a permutation of" relation, then A*/~ is a free commutative monoid.
- **finite sets with union**: If ~ is modified to disregard count of elements (so "aa" ~ "a") then A*/~ is a free commutative idempotent monoid.
- **syntactic monoid**: Any regular language gives rise to syntactic monoid that is quotient of A* by "indistinguishability by language" relation. [Here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/01/fast-incremental-regular-expression.html) is a finger tree implementation of this idea. For example, the language {a<sup>3n</sup>:n natural} has Z<sub>3</sub> as the syntactic monoid.

Quotient monoids automatically come with homomorphism M -> M/~ that is surjective.

A "dual" construction are submonoids. They come with homomorphism A -> M that is injective.

Yet another construction on monoids is [tensor product](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~hsimmons/DOCUMENTS/PAPERSandNOTES/TPoCM.pdf).

Monoids allow exponentation by squaring in O(log n) and fast parallel [prefix sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) computation. Also they are [used in Writer monad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/01/haskell-monoids-and-their-uses.html).

Comment: Thanks; could you tell something about the usefulness of tensor product? The article didn't provide any examples, and I'm not that hardcore at algebra as to think them up myself :)

Answer (score 5):

The Haskell standard library is alternately praised and attacked for its use of the actual mathematical terms for its type classes.  (In my opinion it's a good thing, since without it I'd never even know what a monoid is!).  In any case, you might check out http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Monoid.html for a few more examples:

- the dual of any monoid is a monoid: given a+b, define a new operation ++ with a++b = b+a

  conjunction and disjunction of booleans

  over the Maybe monad (aka "option" in Ocaml), first and last.  That is,

  ```
  first (Just a) b = Just a
  first Nothing b = b
  ```

  and likewise for last

The latter is just the tip of the iceberg of a whole family of monoids related to monads and arrows, but I can't really wrap my head around these (other than simply monadic endomorphisms).  But a google search on `monads monoids` turns up quite a bit.

Comment: Right, I completely forgot about duals and booleans! As for the Maybe monad, the example is essentially mentioned as "Any satisfying predicate". Monad endomorphisms are also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A really useful example of a commutative monoid is unification in logic and constraint languages. See section 2.8.2.2 of 'Concepts, Techniques and Models of Computer Programming' for a precise definition of a possible unification algorithm.

Good luck with your language! I'm doing something similar with a parallel language, using monoids to merge subresults from parallel computations.

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary length Roman numeral value computation.
https://gist.github.com/4542999